# Postgres Not Using Memory

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.4

I am running some spatial queries on tables that have records close to a billion. However, I cannot understand why Postgres is not using the memory in the dedicated server (with 32GB of memory). I tuned the server based on the suggestions in [here](http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/). However, couldn't see any difference in the running time at all and see only under 100Mb of memory usage. I would expect Postgres to consume more memory by loading bigger chunks of data to it; thus, reducing the disk reads and the time. What could I be doing wrong here?

Already looked at these posts:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18484/tuning-postgresql-for-large-amounts-of-ram

http://patshaughnessy.net/2016/1/22/is-your-postgres-query-starved-for-memory

Comment: Is the IO the limiting factor? If so, memory may not help unless you change the IO settings as well, and even at that, readahead isn't just "more is better" in all situations, and RAM is only part of the concern.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info then **[edit]** your question and add the missing information.